# How to check if a prime ramifies, splits or is inert in a non-maximal order of a quadratic number field using Legendre symbol?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

For a quadratic number field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$:

a) A prime $p$ ramifies in the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ if and only if it divides the discriminant $D$ of $\mathcal{O}_K$.

b) A prime $p$ splits in  the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ if $\left(\frac{d}{p}\right)=1$ and, a prime $p$ is inert if $\left(\frac{d}{p}\right)=-1$.

So, for a non-maximal order $\mathcal{O}$ in $K$, do we have any similar results, as in:

i) A prime $p$ ramifies in the order $\mathcal{O}$ if and only if it divides the discriminant $D'$ of $\mathcal{O}$?

ii) A prime $p$ splits in  the order $\mathcal{O}$ if $\left(\frac{d}{p}\right)=1$ and, a prime $p$ is inert if $\left(\frac{d}{p}\right)=-1$? In this case, do all such primes actually splits or are inert, respectively in the order $\mathcal{O}$?

Is this a correct description?

Comment: Just to be sure... you do realize that non-maximal orders in rings of algebraic integers are _not_ Dedekind domains...

Comment: @paulgarrett I understand. Then how can I check whether a prime $p$ ramifies, splits or is inert in a maximal order of a quadratic number field?

Comment: I guess my question is about what you want those words to mean, for non-Dedekind domains. Certainly some senses which are equivalent for finite integrally-closed (hence, Dedekind) extensions of Dedekind domains will cease being equivalent. (I myself would hesitate to attempt to answer your question, because I wouldn't trust myself to _not_ reflexively+subliminally use what I know to be true for Dedekind domains...).

Comment: @paulgarrett I am a bit confused. I know the definitions of these terms in case of a number field. But as you have indicated that since the non-maximal orders are not Dedekind domains, then what is the definitions of these terms in the case of a non-maximal order of a number field?

Comment: Sadly, I myself have no idea about the "best" definition of such things for non-Dedekind domains... What was the context in which this arose? Were there any hints?

Comment: @paulgarrett I was reading this paper https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00208-009-0373-1. On page no. 693 under section 2.2 the primes $l$ in the formula of $C_{E,r}$ this terms comes into play. Since the character $\chi\mathcal{O}(l)$ are defined in a way that seems as if it has something to do with Legendre symbol.

Comment: @paulgarrett The author also mentions on the same page that "Since E is defined over Q, the class number of O must be one, and so “splitting of l in O" makes sense. So, does it mean that we can define these terms similarly as in the case of quadratic fields?

Comment: Hm. I don't know... In $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$, the integral closure is a PID, but I myself do not know how that implies that this ring behaves intelligibly... I think I'm not competent to help you in this, unfortunately.

Comment: Orders have a conductor $f$; primes away from $f$ behave as usual.